# Laravel Dusk Test with same browser Information Every Time

Tags: php, browser, laravel-5.7, laravel-dusk

I want to test my User login Which has browser verification functionality in my Laravel application. I use Laravel Dusk for testing but the problem is Laravel Dusk open a new browser with different browser information for every test. But I need every time I say `php artisan dusk` it has to be the same browser. so I can check my Login Test. Is it possible? if so, How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "browser information"?

Comment: I mean browser cookie

Comment: The only way I see is fetching the cookies at the end of a test and storing them in a file or a database. At the beginning of the next test, you get those cookies and send them to the browser to restore the previous state.

Comment: As we know laravel dusk uses a standalone ChromeDriver, how I get the cookie at the end of the test and also send them at the beginning of the next test?

Comment: Take a look at `$browser->driver->manage()->getCookies()` and `$browser->driver->manage()->addCookie()`.